# C++ nonstatic member reference

Tags: c++, non-static

I have a `Character .h/.cpp`, an `Enemy .h/.cpp` and a `Driver`

If I pass the character into a function from `Enemy`, I have

```
ENEMY.CPP: void Enemy::enemyAttack(Character *character)
{ //whatever needs to be done }
```

which works fine.

But back in my Driver, if I do this:

```
Character *character = new Character();
Enemy::enemyAttack(character);
```

I get the following error message: "A nonstatic member reference must be relative to a specific object." is character not a specific object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the error is talking about an Enemy object. To call a non-static Enemy method you must have an Enemy object.

```
Enemy en;
en.enemyAttack(character);
```

Think about, when you write

```
Enemy::enemyAttack(character);
```

which enemy is it that's attacking? There isn't one.

Answer (score 2):

`enemyAttack` is a non-static member function of `Enemy`. That means you need some `Enemy` object to call it on. Currently you're trying to call it as a static function. You need something like this instead:

```
Enemy monster;
monster.enemyAttack(character);
```

Normally, you would name your function simply `attack`, as it's already a member of `Enemy`. You'll see that it reads better:

```
Enemy monster;
monster.attack(character);
```